# How to make API names into variables for easier coding

Tags: c++, c

I am looking for a way to turn some long and confusing API function names into shorter types to reduce the amount of typing and over all errors due to misspelling.

For example : I would like to take `gtk_functionName();` and make it a variable like so. `doThis = gtk_functionName;`

Sometimes the code will have lots of repeating suffix. I want to know if I can take this `g_signal_connect_` and turn it into this `connect` so I could just type `connectswapped` instead of `g_signal_connect_swapped`.

I am looking to do this in C\C++ but would be happy to know how its done in any language. I thought I had seen a code that did this before but I can not figure out what this would be called so searching for it has been fruitless.

I am sure this is possible and I am just not able to remember how its done.

Comment: Have you looked at function pointers

Comment: @user814628: given the verbosity of the function pointers syntax, the remedy is going to be worse than the illness (unless you have tons of calls to the same function, or you have C++11 `auto`).

Comment: Not really that bad. It's a one time setup for easier alias. Given what he has to work with, function point are a viable option. @MatteoItalia

Comment: FWIW, I'd hate to have to work on a program that renamed all the API functions like that, because even if you know the API already, you have to re-learn all the function names.  Looking up docs for API functions would be a pain because you'd first have to look up the alias just to find out that it's really an API function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are wanting to do is apply the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), which is to present a simplified interface to a larger, more complex body of code.

What this basically means is you define your own simplified interfaces for the functionality you want. The implementation of these interfaces use the longer more complex packages you want to simplify. After that, the rest of your code use the simplified interfaces instead of the complex package directly.

```
void doThis (That *withThat) {
    gtk_functionName(withThat->arg1, withThat->arg2 /* etc. */);
}
```